# Represent Typedef in UML

Tags: c++, struct, uml, typedef

I have a question about Unified Modeling Language (UML) description.
I want to create a UML for my code.
Lets say i have the following header:

```
...

class A;

typedef struct {
  int a;                                  
  int b;                                  
  bool c;                                         
  void (*function)(void*);
  void* obj;
} data;

...
```

Now I want to represent this code as UML.
How should I represent the typedef?

Anyone an idea?

Thanks. :)

Comment: This beside that `class A`, this is C code, not C++.

Comment: You are trying to represent the `struct`, not typedef... typedef is just an alias.